# addToBackStack isn't adding the fragment to the back stack

Tags: android

I have an app with two fragments.  When I tap an item in a list on the first, the app loads the second fragment with this code:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, editFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

That works.  However, when I tap the back button, the app appears to close however it's still running, it just dumps me back to the device's home screen.  I thought to use popBackStack() to return but I discovered that after the code shown above the back stack entry count is still 0 so it looks like the addToBackStack isn't adding anything to the back stack.

I've used this successfully before on other apps and I can't see any difference between this one and the others though there obviously is some difference.

I would really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint.

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the first fragment by calling `add()` followed by `addToBackStack()` you will get the behaviour you describe. Please check that you are not doing calling `addToBackStack()` twice.